# When buttons are removed they lose event handling in Sencha Touch 2.3

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a class called `SettingsBar` that extends `TitleBar` in Sencha Touch 2.3. This `SettingsBar` I'm using has several buttons on it. When you click the `Settings` button then the bar is added to the panel and it shows up just fine.

You can click the buttons on the `SettingsBar` and different things will happen in the app. I have it setup so that you can make the `SettingsBar` disappear if you click the `Settings` button again. So the `Settings` button adds and removes the `SettingsBar`.

When the `SettingsBar` is added, and you click some of the buttons, then the `SettingsBar` is removed, the state of the `SettingsBar` isn't saved. The buttons go back to their original text (their text changes when you click them) and the event handling for them no longer works. You just click them and nothing happens.

Here's my code that adds and removes the `SettingsBar`:

```
settingsTap: function(){
      if(settingsToolbar.added){

          Ext.getCmp('mainview').removeAt(2);
          console.log('added: '+settingsToolbar.added);

      }else{

          Ext.getCmp('mainview').add(settingsToolbar);
          console.log('added: '+settingsToolbar.added);

      }

      settingsToolbar.added = !settingsToolbar.added;
}
```

The event handling is being done in my controller. Why would the buttons be reset and event handling on them removed when the `SettingsBar` is removed from the panel?

Answer (score 1):

This is troublesome and has been asked for several times.

The safest way which even works when you destroy the component completely when removing it (you should always do, it reclaims a lot of memory), is to declare the event handlers in the `initialize` function of that component, or its parent component, wherever you think suitable, for example:

```
initialize: function(){
    var me = this;
    me.add({
        xtype: 'list',
        grouped: true,
        indexBar: true,
        itemTpl: '{first} {last}',
        listeners: [
            {
                event: 'itemtap',
                fn: function(dataview, index, target, record, e){
                    // do something
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

This is an example for `itemtap` event on a `Ext.List`. Let's adapt it to your case.

Answer (score 0):

By default, child components are destroyed when they are removed from a container. When speaking of Ext components, "destroy" means **removing all listeners** and references, so that the object can be cleaned out by the garbage collector.

You can prevent destruction of removed components by changing the [`autoDestroy`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-autoDestroy) option of the container (the title bar, in your case). Don't forget however that you'll have to call the [`destroy`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-destroy) method of each components yourself when you're done with them, or you'll be creating a memory leak in your app.

Comment: This kind of worked. I added `autoDestroy: false` to the config of my view (no where else worked) and it is working. The button text still goes back to it's original state though. So do the variables in the controller that I made that signify if the button was clicked or not. Is there any way to prevent that? Is there a property on objects that lets you say that the specific object can't be destroyed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your problem well enough to help you any further... I think I would need to see your code running to completely understand what happens.